# Would the Earth become a black hole due to excess of information?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, information

I was reading 'Welcome to The Universe', where in the appendix is a situation in which a hard disk, 7.5 cm in diameter, stores more and more information, before eventually becoming a black hole.

Similarly, the amount of information we use is exponentially increasing in our world. So, if in the future, we develop computers around the world, and feed them too much data, then could the entire Earth just turn into a black hole? And, how much information (and change in entropy) would it require?

Comment: Hard disks do not grow when you store data in them. So what do you mean with feeding data.

Comment: I read that their mass increases. In everyday amounts it would be negligible.

Comment: By feeding data, I mean given them some program which requires huge amounts of data to run.